# Using leaflet to determine if a line intersects through a polygon

Tags: leaflet, turfjs

I am trying to work out the best way to determine if a line goes through a polygon, where it is possible that that points on that line do no fall within the polygon as shown in image below.

My data is multiple polygons and I wish to see if a line (lat,long to lat,long) goes through 1 or more of the polygons.

leaflet has a leaflet-pip that does a point in a polygon but I need to test a line... turf.js has lineIntersect but would this work with a line and a polygon (JSON)? Is there something else I can use but haven't found yet?

Just after some advice on the best way or library to achieve this

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanIntersects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turf booleanIntersects works nicely.
Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ripkk?file=/src/index.js:9634-9641